# check dll exist and based on that use properties of that class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dll, assemblies

I need to implement Report level dll where if we added that dll then some repors will show..For that i have created class library CustomeReports..in this class file i have listing some dynamic reports as you can see below code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomeReports
{
    public class keyPairTextC
    {
        public bool keyID { get; set; }
        public string keyN { get; set; }
        public string keyE { get; set; }
        public string keyFromDate { get; set; }
        public string keyTillDate { get; set; }        

    }
    public class CustomReport
    {   
        public List<keyPairTextC> GetReportNameList()
        {
            CustomReport rpt = new CustomReport();
            List<keyPairTextC> getReportName = new List<keyPairTextC>();
            getReportName.Add(new keyPairTextC
            {
                keyID = false,
                keyN = "Report2",
                keyE = "R",
                keyFromDate = "NA",
                keyTillDate = "NA",               
            });
            return getReportName;
        }        
        public static string getKeyEmp(string strPropertyValue)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> newList1 = new List<string>();
                newList1 = getKeyValue(strPropertyValue).Select(C => C.keyE).ToList();
                strPropertyValue = newList1[0].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strPropertyValue = "";
            }
            return strPropertyValue;
        }
        public static List<keyPairTextC> getKeyValue(string strPropertyValue)
        {
            List<keyPairTextC> newList = new List<keyPairTextC>();
            CustomReport crm = new CustomReport();
            newList = crm.GetReportNameList();
            newList = newList.Where(c => c.keyN.Contains(strPropertyValue)).ToList();
            return newList;
        }
    }
}
```

And now i want to use this class method getReportNameList to bind this report in case i am adding this dll or reference of this library.

So in my aspx form i have below code...

```
var className = "CustomReports";
            var assemblyName = "CustomeReports, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
            foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            {
                if (a.FullName == assemblyName)
                {
                    assembly = a;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (assembly != null)
            {
                ViewState["AssemblyInfo"] = assembly;
                hdnDLLValue.Value = "1";
                string strReportName = "Custom Reports";                                               
                object result = null;
                result = returnDLLObject("GetReportNameList");
            }
```

i have return dll Object in below method

```
public object returnDLLObject(string MethodName)
        {
            string className = "CustomeReports.CustomReports"; 
            object result = null;
            object classInstance = null;
            if (assembly == null)
                assembly=(Assembly)ViewState["AssemblyInfo"];

            if (assembly != null)
            {
                try
                {

                    Type _type_2 = assembly.GetType(className);
                    var methodInfo = _type_2.GetMethod(MethodName);
                    ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
                    classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(_type_2, null);
                    if (parameters.Length == 0)
                    {
                        result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object[] parametersArray = new object[] { ViewState["nodevalue"].ToStringIC() };
                        result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   result=null;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

so now i am unable to bind this report object into list type Class and also unable to get property value from that class library....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too Many searching i found way to find dll and use keypairtext properties ....thanks to `dynamic keyword`

here is my below code in aspx page to find dll and then use that class library properties..

This is method to check file and dll is exist return boolean value

```
        internal static bool FileOrDirectoryExists(string name)
        {
            return (Directory.Exists(name) || File.Exists(name));
        }
```

and on my page load i have function to bind reports so in below code you can see

```
string path = Server.MapPath(@"../CustomReports/CustomeReports.dll");

        if (FileOrDirectoryExists(path))
        {
            var className = "CustomReports";
            var ProductVersion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path).ProductVersion;
            var assemblyName = "CustomeReports, Version=" + ProductVersion.ToStringIC() + ", Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
            assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

           // ViewState["AssemblyInfo"] = assembly;
            hdnDLLValue.Value = "1";
            string strReportName = "Custom Reports";
            object result = null;
            result = returnDLLObject("GetReportNameList");
            int a = SpectraBL.Application.AccessControl.ToInt32IC();

            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result is IEnumerable)
                {
                    List<object> list = new List<object>();
                    var enumerator = ((IEnumerable)result).GetEnumerator();
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        list.Add(enumerator.Current);
                    }
                    List<dynamic> dynamicList = list.Select(x => (dynamic)x).ToList();
                    if (dynamicList.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Childnode = new TreeNode("<span id='reportgrp' class='reportmenu label' onclick= OnNodeClick('G','" + strReportName + "','1'); > " + strReportName + " </span>", "Dynamic Reports");
                        Childnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
                        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Childnode);
                        for (var i = 0; i < dynamicList.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string strChildName = dynamicList[i].ReportName;
                            if (dynamicList[i].isDisplay)
                            {
                                TreeNode Namenode = new TreeNode();
                                if (ReportID == dynamicList[i].Reportid)
                                {
                                    //With selection on pageload
                                    Namenode = new TreeNode("<span id='report" + dynamicList[i].ReportName + "' class='reportmenu label selected' onclick= OnNodeClick('C','" + dynamicList[i].Reportid + "','1'); > " + strChildName + " </span>", strChildName);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //Without selection
                                    Namenode = new TreeNode("<span id='report" + dynamicList[i].ReportName + "' class='reportmenu label' onclick= OnNodeClick('C','" + dynamicList[i].Reportid + "','1'); > " + strChildName + " </span>", strChildName);
                                }
                                Namenode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
                                Childnode.ChildNodes.Add(Namenode);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

here is my returnDLLObject method...which will create instance of the class and return object..

```
public object returnDLLObject(string MethodName)
        {
            string className = "CustomeReports.CustomReports";
            object result = null;
            object classInstance = null;
            string path = Server.MapPath(@"../CustomReports/CustomeReports.dll");

           // if (!FileOrDirectoryExists(path))
            assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);

            if (FileOrDirectoryExists(path))
            {
                try
                {
                    Type _type_2 = assembly.GetType(className);
                    var methodInfo = _type_2.GetMethod(MethodName);
                    ParameterInfo[] parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
                    classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(_type_2, null);
                    if (parameters.Length == 0)
                    {
                        result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object[] parametersArray = new object[] { ViewState["nodevalue"].ToStringIC() };
                        result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Error.BLErrorDesc = ex.Message;
                    result = null;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

If you have any query or doubt then let me know and will discuss...thank you...;)